# How do you create a custom user role in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Found this [article](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) on how to setup roles but it uses the legacy azure portal to accomplish this.

How do you create user roles in the latest Azure portal?

How do you assign multiple roles to a user afterwards?

Comment: Are you looking for Azure AD roles or Azure Subscription roles?

Comment: Looking for Azure AD Roles

Comment: According to your article you found, I assume that you want to assign users and groups to application roles, not create a custom user role in Azure AD...This question title may mislead us .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From December 2015, you can create your own RBAC roles.

You can get clear idea via this **[`Custom Roles in Azure RBAC`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-Active-Directory-Videos-Demos/Custom-Roles-in-Azure-RBAC)**

Answer (score 1):

[**RBAC built-in**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles) roles lists the roles available in Azure. It specifies the operations and scope that each built-in role grants to users. If you're looking to define your own roles for even more control, see how to build **[Custom roles in Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles)**.

Answer (score 1):

According to article your referred, I assume that you want to assign users and groups to application roles.

You can achieve this from new portal. But Only Azure AD Premium or Enterprise mobility suite support assigning **with roles**. You can take following steps:

Go to Azure portal > Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > All applications > Select your application > Users and Groups

[image]

Now, you can assign roles through adding users(My Azure AD is not basic):

[image]